How to prevent TransactionRolledBackException in ActiveMQ
We have a consumer (C# application) that subscribes to a queue of ActiveMQ Classic. We are using AcknowledgementMode.Transactional to create the session.
Connection URI:
activemq:failover://(tcp://broker1.com:61780)?randomize=false&amp;transport.maxReconnectAttempts=3&amp;transport.reconnectDelay=3000&amp;connection.prefetchPolicy.queuePrefetch=1

There are many instances this application running and each is functioning well.
Receives the message in the consumer app which sends ack (_session.Commit()) to the broker. This process has been running with no issue until recently where our network has some intermittent glitches.
On such cases, the AMQ broker is throwing the TransactionRolledBackException from the method _session.Commit()
Here is the full stack trace:
Apache.NMS.TransactionRolledBackException: Transaction completion in doubt due to failover. Forcing rollback of ID:qcyp-slack-03-64154-638666766860410819-1:3826:5
   at Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ.Connection.SyncRequest(Command command, TimeSpan requestTimeout)
   at Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ.TransactionContext.Commit()
   at Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ.Session.DoCommit()
   at MyCompany.ActiveMQ.ActiveMqClient.Commit()
   at MyCompany.Core.Messaging.Pooling.AvailableMessageQueueClient.Commit()

This issue is intermittent. From our research and analysis of our logs, it is found that when we get this TransactionRolledBackException, the broker rolled back the transaction and hence that same message will be delivered to another consumer.
Now, my question is how we can prevent such an exception or how can we make our application more resilient to such issues?

How specifically does your application need to be "more resilient" to transaction rollbacks? Why is it not resilient at the moment? Your question is currently too vague and is liable to be closed.

Any feedback on this question?

The request here is to account for potential network or connectivity issues between the application and the ActiveMQ broker. Recognizing that such issues may occur, we aim to enhance the application to minimize the impact, specifically reducing the frequency of TransactionRollBackException occurrences.

The transaction rollback itself accounts for the connectivity issue(s) does it not? It allows your application to deal with the failure in a graceful way. It's not clear to me specifically needs to be dealt with in your application to make it "more resilient." Can you clarify this? Also, if you want to reduce instances of transaction rollbacks due to network instability then you need to stabilize your network. It's really as simple as that.

The only way to completely prevent transaction rollbacks is to ensure the operating environment never has any problems (e.g. network glitches) and your application never has any bugs (e.g. crashes while processing a message).
However, that's a completely unrealistic goal. There will always be problems, and, in fact, this is one of the main reasons transactions were created in the first place. A transaction rollback is a feature, not a bug. It is a graceful way to handle a failure, and your application should be able to deal with it. In theory, your application should be able to consume the message again and suffer no ill effects.

Thanks, Justin! After our investigation, we found that setting maxReconnectAttempts=0 causes an infinite number of reconnection attempts between the broker and client before any error is sent to the client, as per the AMQ documentation. Our QA environment doesn’t display this issue, so we weren’t able to replicate it in a lower environment and thus couldn’t validate this option.
Would you recommend an indefinite retry approach? Could it potentially lead to a connection leak?

Alternatively, we’re considering increasing maxReconnectAttempts from our current setting of 3 to around 10. This would extend the reconnection timeframe and may help mitigate issues caused by intermittent network or socket disruptions.

As a third option, we’re currently using Transactional acknowledgment mode, but based on the documentation, IndividualAcknowledge lacks a built-in rollback mechanism. We haven’t pursued this solution yet, as it may require further investigation. Thanks!!

How could any error be sent to the client after "an infinite number of reconnection attempts"? If the reconnect attempts are infinite then they should never end, right? Whether infinite retries makes sense for your application really depends on your specific use-case. There isn't enough information here to provide you with a recommendation. In any case, there shouldn't be a connection leak unless there is a bug in the client.
